# App for phone and tablet

Tags: android, delphi, google-play, tablet, delphi-xe7

I generated a test application and published in the Play Store (Google).

But when looking for the app in Play Store, using a tablet, it does not appear! If you use the phone, the application appears available.

- In the development environment, I can run the same application on both devices.
- The images requested in google play for tablet (7 "and 10") were filled as size specification.
- Already added to the project, in the "Style" ANDROID, all the "Views" available (3.5", 4", 5", 7" and 10")

Is there a specific feature in Play Store or in the code that needs to be "activated" in applications to tablet?

What should be done to provide for tablet?

Comment: Does the app require phone capabilities? See [Apps missing on Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/189028?hl=en) and http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your android manifest.xml file in your build folder. Maybe you've specified only small screens.

You should add/have this in your manifest file:

```
<supports-screens
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

If you don't have this you can add it by adding it to your manifest template in your project folder. If you have something like  you should try to delete that.